# System( "pause" ) Causes Heap Corruption

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

So this is very strange and there might be a really simple explanation for this, but I'm using a machine I don't normally develop on with a factory-default installation of VS 2010. The code posted below is exactly what I am running, and it's causing this familiar message:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ProjectB.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in ProjectB.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while ProjectB.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

That's it! Nothing more and only one file. Commenting out system( "pause" ) doesn't trigger the break, but I can't stop the program from exiting (as you would expect). So I'm really confused. This just seems really strange to me, as I've never experienced this before and I don't understand why this causes an issue. Using another system command that doesn't stop the process (like system( "cls" )) doesn't cause the problem, either. My inclination is that this is specific to the machine I'm working on, but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

Any help is appreciated.

[EDIT]

So I've never debugged into the standard headers (at least not purposefully) before, but I noticed one thing:

In `__crtCorExitProcess` the call to load the mscoree.dll module returns a null handle, meaning it's not loaded. I'm not sure if that's what normally happens, but in doing so it skips a block of code that gets the exit proc function pointer. It is after this method is called that a call to `ExitProcess` is called, and it is from here that the break is triggered.

[EDIT 2]

> The following is produced in the output window after the call the `system( "pause" )`:
>   First-chance exception at 0x750cc41f in ProjectB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: >log4cxx::helpers::IOException at memory location 0x006ff1fc..
>   First-chance exception at 0x750cc41f in ProjectB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: >log4cxx::helpers::IOException at memory location 0x006ff344..
>   SPLogger: setFile(C:\ProgramData\Safend\Logs.18698\SPHook.log,true) call failed.
>   SPLogger: IO Exception : status code = 720005
>   SPLogger: No output stream or file set for the appender named [SPHookLog].

And then when ExitProcess is called, this is added to the output window:

> The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ca8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   HEAP[ProjectB.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 21a4ba8 modified at 21a4c10 after it was freed

Which is curious to me.

Comment: Note that `<iostream>` doesn't give you any guarantees whatsoever about included C headers, so `<cstdlib>` is actually required. But that shouldn't be the source of the error.

Comment: Thanks; I added the <cstdlib> include and this did not solve the issue either.

Comment: This smells like a runtime library mismatch to me.

Comment: If @MarkB's excellent idea doesn't lead anywhere, I think this problem is probably too system-specific to be solved here, unless someone stumbled over it before and happens to know the solution. However, in such a situation I would recommend a few things: Update VS to the latest service pack. Completely clean the project, manually deleting output folders if necessary, and rebuild; or try making a new project and copying stuff over.

Comment: How would I tell if there's a runtime lib mismatch?

Comment: Seeing Edit 2: That looks like you're linking in `log4cxx` for some reason, and it's picking up a weird configuration file from somewhere, and possibly the `pause` command is messing up the stdio settings.

Comment: I'm using a work machine to and trying to test out a simple algorithm; thought I would create a basic C++ console and try it. I created a new empty project from VS, added the code, and now we're here. Do you think there is something system-specific going on here that may be out of my control?

Comment: *This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while ProjectB.exe has focus.*  Don't you think that might be a factor somehow?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not pressing F12.

Comment: I just compiled the program with VS2010, both debug and release version worked fine. If you have anti virus software on your machine, please shut down it  and try again. I once encounter a strange crash problem and it is due to the anti virus software inject a DLL to the process and it used a different version of runtime library.

Comment: @Matt I have a feeling this may be the cause, as there's a ton of security software running that is out of my control.

Comment: Aparently you have some "hooks" instaled on the system, that are creating some log files... try to run the Visual Studio as a Administrator to see if it's a security permissions problem.

Comment: But you are doing *pause*, which is probably in many ways equivalent.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto Running as admin doesn't lift the hooks either. Thanks, though.

Comment: I think you can use two tools from systeminteral: process monitor and process explorer. The first one can record the loading sequence of the DLLs, try to find the DLL which should not be loaded for your program and check the dependency of these Dlls.

Comment: Thanks everyone for really looking into this with me. I've concluded it's probably out of my control to fix this at work, and it's not that imperative; just annoying. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that there is security software running that is preventing certain DLL's from being loaded and/or injecting code to prevent malicious instructions from being executed. Since I've never experienced this on a personal machine and am only experiencing this on a corporate box that has a lot of security administration going on, I think it is that. I doubt it is a runtime mismatch, as nothing else produces unexpected results. Thank you everyone who commented with potential problems! Read the comments if you're having this issue, as there are other potential issues discussed there.